# Read large csv file into R

Tags: r, csv

I am working in RStudio with R version 2.15.1. I saved an Excel file in CSV file and imported that to R
(with the `read.csv()` function). When I do `dim(file)`, I got:

```
[1] 4920 23
```

But when I tried to retrieve the very first element with `file[1:1]`, I got the entire first column! 
Why is that?

Comment: use a comma `file[1,1]`. `file[1:1]` tells R to take the first list (data frames are a collection of lists) and `:` says basically 'go until' the last list, also 1 in your case, so it returns all from 1 until 1, which would just be (all of) column 1.

Comment: Try fread(): ```require(data.table)
DT <- fread("test.csv")```  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r

Comment: what is the real dim()?

Answer (score 3):

you need comas for each dimension. So

```
file[i, j]
```

is the element on the i^{th} row and j^{th} column.  If you want the whole first row, the proper way to do it is to type

```
file[1, ]
```

What you did is useful in selecting several rows. So if you type

```
file[c(1:4),]
```

will select the first 4 columns and so on.  In your particular case what you want to type is:

```
file[1, 1]
```

Comment: you don't need the `c()`

Comment: You've mixed up rows/columns in your explanation here, which I presume is simply a typo.